# Microsoft Graph API provide user consent without UI flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a Azure Active Directory application and I have provided some of the user delegated permissions for accessing Graph APIs. For example 'user.read' and 'user.read.all' etc.

To provide `User Consent` for the Graph APIs which have Delegated permission. I need to login using my credentials to the test application (I developed) and then there will be a Popup displayed on the Web UI with title "Permissions requested" to grand the consent. I need to select `Accept` button to grand the consent.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a way we can preauthorize the user consent without following Web UI flow?
2. Just like the admin consent in Active Directory, is there a way to grant user consent?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible through MS Graph API.

When you grant user consent, an OAuth2PermissionGrant object is created.
Admin consent also creates one but in that one the principal is set to be "all users".
You can also create these programmatically.

You can see the docs for the API endpoint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
It is created under the service principal of your app and you specify consentType as "Principal" and principalId as the user's objectId.

Comment: Thanks for the details. My question was more about granting user consent using the Azure Portal just like we do in the Admin Consent and not using the APIs or programmatically.

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible.

Comment: As per your answer it is possible using the Graph API were user will not need to login using the UI flow. I have gone through the doc link. I have few questions: 1. What is the "resourceId" in the request and how we get/generate it?  2. "principalId" is the ID of the user for whom the permissions are granted? 3. Can this API flow be used to grand 'presence.read.all' delegated permission?

Comment: 1. resourceId = objectId / id of the target service principal (aka enterprise application). This identifies the target API. 2. Correct, principalId = objectId / id of user. 3. I would imagine it can be granted.

Comment: Thanks for the details, will it be possible to post the example POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to hit this url and signed in with the admin account, then you may consent on behalf of your organization. This url is used to get auth code for using auth code flow(generate access token)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/hanxia.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=your_azure_ad_app_clientid
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=user.read
&state=12345
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need, if it's not, please kindly let me know and I'll delete it

Comment: @Tinu Wang: No I am not looking for this solution. I am looking for something which can be don in the Azure portal without using APIs or programmatically.

Comment: ms graph api is provided by microsoft so it is designed that some of the api permissions require admin concent. It doesn't allow `user consent` from my knowledge...

Comment: So you mean to say there is no other way then to provide user consent other than UI flow?

Comment: I don't know other ways to consent api permission except click the `grant` in azure portal. Maybe take a try to use Fiddler to capture request?

Comment: The "grant" option in Azure AD portal is available only for the Admin consent and not for the user delegated permission. User need to provide the consent using the flow you have given in the answer.

Comment: Ok, I really misunderstood... And `What is the "resourceId" in the request` -- I'm afraid it is the azure ad app id which exposed api. I think you may used azure ad to exposed an api and add scope `presence.read.all`, then the resource id should be the id of this application.